# Is it possible to make GTM to tag some elements that are dynamically created

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager

I'm a React developer and I barely knows how GTM works as it's not my field.

What I understand is

- There are `trigger`s on google tag manager
- GTM script will find HTML elements of the triggers by defined css selectors(in my case) and tag them(put GTM attributes) when it's loaded in the page
- When an event meeting the condition of a trigger occurs, the trigger will execute defined javascript(in my case)

The problem is that HTML elements possibly don't exist when GTM script is tagging because they can be created by a user interaction. And I want to tag such elements by using GTM's lifecycle method(if exists). Is there any way to do this or at least a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The best practice I can come up with is something like :

When you render the element you want to track in the React.

Let React push the datalayer about the information of the element like

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.dataLayer.push({ 
  event: "element_render",
  element_id: "#id",
  element_type: "type",
  any_paramter_you_need: "any_value_you_need",
})
```

So you can set up the `Trigger` in you Google Tag Manager and the type is `Custom Event`

[image]

Comment: While it should be possible to capture this via built-in triggers in GTM, I wholeheartedly that this is the most reliable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that should work out of the box. GTM does not tag elements directly. Instead, GTM is attached to the document root. If an element is clicked, the event bubbles up to the document root, and there GTM checks if the properties of the event target (the actually element interacted with) meet the conditions defined in the trigger.

So unless React is doing something super crazy with the document, you should be safe. Allowing to track dynamically added elements is pretty much the point of this design.

For visibility triggers, you specifically need to enable this behavior by clicking the checkbox on "observe DOM changes". There is a warning that this might impact page speed.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I guessed so for click triggers, but what about view triggers? Does GTM also observe view events of new elements? From what I observed of how GTM works with view trigger, it doesn't seem to register `MutationObserver` and `IntersectionObserver` for new elements.

Comment: Well, it works on our website :-). You have to enable that in the visibility trigger, and they warn you that there is a performance penalty.

Comment: It's strange that for my case, GTM doesn't always ignore new elements. And when GTM ignores them, there is a specific pattern that I cannot reason, as the css selector of those new elements are still same